# Is it possible to install gui in ubuntu server 10.10?

Tags: installation, 10.10, server, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software on an old now unsupported Ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-on-an-old-now-unsupported-ubuntu-version)

I tried this:

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

But i got this error:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-icon-theme/gnome-icon-theme_2.31.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed
```

Then i tried to install `gnome-icon-theme` by myself, but I can't find 10.10's `gnome-icon-theme` in http://pkgs.org/download/gnome-icon-theme. :-(

Comment: ubuntu 10.10 no longer supported

Comment: @mikewhatever's comment should point you in the right direction. Please also remember to run `sudo apt-get update` before running `sudo apt-get install ...` (or `sudo apt-get upgrade`).